# twigで作成したテンプレートのタグがエスケープされない

Tags: php, html, mail, twig

お世話になります。
twigでメールのテンプレートを作成しているのですが、
実際に以下のソースを読み込んで送信したメールに`<ul>`や `<li>`などの
タグも含まれた形（メールの文面にタグが表示されている）で送信されてしまいます。
タグをエスケープしたいのですが、どのように書けばいいのかがわかりません。
お手数をおかけしますが、ご教授だけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

```
<ul>　
{% for item in update.items %}
<li>{{ item.id }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: 「タグをエスケープしたい」とありますが、タグをHTMLとして機能させなくすることが「エスケープ」になります。つまりタグとして機能していないただのテキストの状況になっている今の状態はエスケープされていることになります。正確にはHTMLメールとして機能させたいということですか？それともタグを除去したいということですか？

Comment: わかりづらく手すみません。。

Comment: やりたいこととしては、タグの除去したいです。

Comment: であればタグを除去したテンプレートを別で作ればよいのではないですか？

Comment: 早速、やってみようと思います。ありがとうございます！